# Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration-Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, h2

following is my code

**Spring boot Entry class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.assertmanagementdigital4.repositories")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan("com.test.assertmanagementdigital4")
public class AssertManagementDigital4Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AssertManagementDigital4Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

@RestController
public class ShopController {

```
    @Autowired
    private ShopService shopService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/shops",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void shopDetails(@RequestBody Shop shop){
        shopService.addShopDetails(shop);

    }

}
```

**entities**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ShopDetails")
public class Shop {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String shopName;
    private Address address;

    public String getShopName() {
        return shopName;
    }

    public void setShopName(String shopName) {
        this.shopName = shopName;
    }

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="add_Id")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Shop [id=" + id + ", shopName=" + shopName + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }


}
```

**spring data repository**

```
@Repository
public interface ShopRepository extends CrudRepository<Shop,Long>{

}
```

**Service classs**

```
@Service
public class ShopService {
    @Autowired
    private ShopRepository shopRepository;

    public void addShopDetails(Shop shop) {
        shopRepository.save(shop);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
#spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username:sa
spring.datasource.password:
spring.datasource.driver-class-name:org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform:h2

  # enable H2 web console and set url for web console
  # http://localhost:8080/console
  spring.h2.console.enabled:true
  spring.h2.console.path:/console
```

**build.gradle**

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

I know this question is already posted by someone but that does not solved my problem I'm still getting the following error ,could you please let me know what is wrong with this

```
Description:

Field shopRepository in com.test.assertmanagementdigital4.service.ShopService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

If I remove exclude auto configuration, I got following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at com.test.assertmanagementdigital4.AssertManagementDigital4Application.main(AssertManagementDigital4Application.java:20) [bin/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: address, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(shop)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Well you explicitly disabled auto configuration for JPA so obviously there is no auto configured `EntityManagerFactory`. Either remove the exclude or manually define a `EntityManagerFactory`. Also your `spring.datasource` properties are pretty much useless as well as you also exclude auto configuration for the datasource.

Comment: please check update above

Comment: Don't post a snippet of a stack trace, post the full stracktrace.

Comment: M.Deinum I have posted full stacktrace

Comment: You cannot combine annotations on fields and set/get methods. Either use the field level or set/get methods not both. Also the error is in your `Address` class not posted here.

Comment: I thought Address class is no way related to this that's why I did not post here but error was just because of Address class I just temp comment on address from shop and its working ,you are excellent thank you so much for your help solved now.

Answer (score 5):

If you dismiss auto configuration, then you should provide it by yourself.

See example:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws URISyntaxException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(your_datasource);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(package_to_scan);
    //additional config of factory

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) throws URISyntaxException {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i am having the same issue. I have added entityManagerFactory and jpaTransactionManager but after that, it is giving me an error as "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?". any suggestion in that ?

Comment: @DhiralKaniya, I'm not sure your exact case, but can try to help if you share your stacktrace. You can create new question and share with me, if question is still open. As I know, your exception means that you have defined circular references in beans. I guess that your `entityManagerFactory` depends on some bean that has `entityManagerFactory` dependency.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this piece of code, just remove it.

```
public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Spent around 40 minutes and then find this.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is due to tomcat connection pooling. Try to add following dependency in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

It solved my problem.

Comment: It worked previously but not working in my current project. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved when I have updated my spring boot parent version to 2.1.1 in pom.xml

```
<!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```