# How do I define entityManagerFactory bean in my configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, javabeans

I am working on a spring boot project for a simple employee management system using JPA. This is my first project in spring. I am getting an error with this entityManagerFactory bean as described in the title. I am trying to understand where to define the bean(s) that it is mentioning/ where my "configuration" is.

My project structure is setup as below:

```
src/
├── main/
│   └── java/
|       └── com.example.springbootproject/
|           ├── SpringBootApplication.java
|           ├── controller/
|           |   └── EmployeeController.java
|           ├── model/
|           |   └── Employee.java
|           ├── repository/
|           |   └── EmployeeRepository.java
|           └── service/
|               ├── EmployeeService.java
|               └── EmployeeServiceImpl.java
└── resources/
    └── application.properties
```

The code for the java files, application.properties, and pom.xml is below.

This is the **EmployeeController.java** file

```java
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
        return findPaginated(1, "employeeName", "asc", model);
    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String showNewEmployeeForm(Model model) {
        Employee Employee = new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee", Employee);
        return "newEmployee";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
        // save Employee to database
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @GetMapping("/update/{id}")
    public String showFormForUpdate(@PathVariable( value = "id") long id, Model model) {

        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "updateEmployee";
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable (value = "id") long id) {

        this.employeeService.deleteEmployeeById(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }


    @GetMapping("/page/{pageNo}")
    public String findPaginated(@PathVariable (value = "pageNo") int pageNo,
                                @RequestParam("sortField") String sortField,
                                @RequestParam("sortDir") String sortDir,
                                Model model) {
        int pageSize = 5;

        Page<Employee> page = employeeService.findPaginated(pageNo, pageSize, sortField, sortDir);
        List<Employee> listEmployees = page.getContent();

        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNo);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());

        model.addAttribute("sortField", sortField);
        model.addAttribute("sortDir", sortDir);
        model.addAttribute("reverseSortDir", sortDir.equals("asc") ? "desc" : "asc");

        model.addAttribute("listEmployees", listEmployees);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

This is the **Employee.java** class

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "employee_first_name")
    private String employeeFirstName;
    @Column(name = "employee_last_name")
    private String employeeLastName;
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private String employeeID;
    @Column(name = "employee_email")
    private String employeeEmail;
}
```

This is the **EmployeeService.java** class

```java
public interface EmployeeService {
    List<Employee> getAllEmployees();
    void saveEmployee(Employee employee);
    Employee getEmployeeById(long id);
    void deleteEmployeeById(long id);
    Page<Employee> findPaginated(int pageNum, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection);
}
```

This is the **EmployeeServiceImpl.java** class

```java
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(long id) {
        Optional<Employee> optionalEmployee = employeeRepository.findById(id);
        Employee employee = null;
        if (optionalEmployee.isPresent()) {
            employee = optionalEmployee.get();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Employee not found for id : " + id);
        }
        return employee;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployeeById(long id) {
        this.employeeRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Employee> findPaginated(int pageNum, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection) {
        Sort sort = sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() :
                Sort.by(sortField).descending();

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNum - 1, pageSize, sort);
        return this.employeeRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

**application.properties** only has the following line
`spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration`

**pom.xml** has the following dependencies

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootProject</name>
    <description>SpringBootProject</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run the application, the console spits out

```
2023-02-25T17:33:41.469-05:00 ERROR 2680 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field employeeRepository in com.example.springbootproject.service.EmployeeServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

I was originally being told to

> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.springbootproject.repository.EmployeeRepository' in your configuration.

but after adding `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.springbootproject.repository")` it resulted in the entityManagerFactory error.

I have checked online thinking maybe the dependencies were off but there seem to be no issues there.

Another question encountered the same error, [Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration-Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516942/consider-defining-a-bean-named-entitymanagerfactory-in-your-configuration-spri)

but I am unsure if this is relevant to the issue I am having, or where this could be implemented. New package? Existing one?

Comment: I think you need to add something like this in your repository -> Page<Employee> findAll(Pageable pageable);

Comment: Which DB are you using? There are some starters missing in pom.xml and some  spring.datasource properties missing from application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add bean in @Configuration annotated class.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.springbootproject.repository")
@Configuration
public class DataJpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.springbootproject.model");

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager dbTransactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

change vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform() depending on your database